# I have list of emails in Excel sheet. What is the simplest way to search records from database which contains the same emails from the Excel file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

In an Excel sheet, it contains information of people and also their email similar to this.

```
S.N    Email
1      short@abc.com
2      medium@xyzabc.com
3      abc@def.com
4      veryverylongemail@abcdefghijkl.com
5      averagesizemail@abc.com
...................................
// there are hundreds of more emails like these
```

In the database, suppose there is a `table` named `Persons` which contains all information about people. Now I want to get only those records in which UserEmail column contains the above list of emails.

Although I can copy paste all emails, and search in database using query something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE USEREMAIL IN (
'short@abc.com',
'medium@xyzabc.com',
'veryverylongemail@abcdefghijkl.com'
..... )
```

**Since there are hundreds of emails, so this will be time consuming because I will have to insert quotation in each email front and back along and also comma. I am looking for a simpler solution.**

What is the simplest way to search those records ? I just want to search the records contains those emails.

Comment: Insert all these emails from excel into a temp table and then write your query.

Answer (score 0):

You should import an excel file in SQL server using the import data option.
Go to SQL server management studio (SSMS)
Right-click on your Database -> Click Tasks -> Click Import data

Once data is imported in the SQL Server table.

You can write query like this  -

```
SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE USEREMAIL IN ( Select Email from <YourExcelImportedDataTableName> Where Email  is Not null)
```